# generic JSON message handling without a domain object

Tags: spring-integration

I am calling a web service that is returning a json message. 
In my spring integration application i want to have a generic processing of this message (without having to write a domain object) by converting it into pipe delimited key value pair and build the downstream flow based on tokens. How would i approach this in spring-integration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `json-to-object-transformer` to create, e.g. a `LinkedHashMap` from the JSON, the use a custom transformer to transform the map to your format.